# unable to execute multiple commands in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, putty

I am new to unix and scripting, need your help for the below scenario.
These are the contents of my .sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
usrun xyz
whoami
```

When I am calling this bash file from putty its asking me for my xyz user's password some other information to properly log in the xyz user.
After successfully login, the $ sign in putty changes to #### xyz$, so I am guessing its opening a new session for the xyz user.
However, after that, the `whoami` command is not getting executed. Only after I type `exit` the `whoami` command is getting executed.

why is this happening? How to execute the whoami command after successful authentication of xyz user?

The #### represents the last four digits of my server to which I am currently connected to via putty.

Comment: Shell scripts are typically executed from the machine they are intended to touch.  If you want to run them remotely, then you have to include that information either at execution, or in your script. There are many answers that already cover this information on executing shell scripts against remote servers including this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments

Comment: It sounds like `usrun` opens a new shell; your script blocks until that shell exits, *then* runs `whoami`. You need some way of specify `whoami` as the command that `usrun` should execute.

Comment: Thanks Michael..for link..although I am not able to make this script work.

Comment: Hi chepner, yes I am stuck at that point..How to specify whoami as the command that usrun should execute..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `usrun` command without any parameters blocks the execution of the bash script. Thus, until the command is not finished (when you type exit), the next command (`whoami`) is not executed.

If you want to login into the machine and execute a command you should try:

```
#!/bin/bash
usrun -u xyz whoami
```

The `-u` option allows you to specify the user and next you can provide the command to execute.

If you want to execute more than one command in the remote machine using Putty I suggest you to follow something similar to this post:

https://superuser.com/questions/1103873/how-to-type-commands-in-putty-by-creating-batch-file

Comment: Hi Christián..I tried the above approach you suggested but it didn't work for me as when I am trying to execute the command am getting permission denied exception..

Comment: I have done some basic reading on usrun it basically provides privileged user access control, in their novel site they also specified that usrun -u xyz "command" will execute but in my case it's not happening..  it's directly trying to execute the command without authentication prompt and which is causing the permission denied issue..

Comment: Are you suggesting #! /bin/bash usrun xyz -u xyz whoami ? Am not able to format my answer as I am using the app for posting the comments.

Comment: accepting you're answer especially for the link you've provided. hope with that link's discussion I can move ahead further.. thanks @Cristian

Comment: I am sorry I hadnt been able to look at this for some days. According to the Novell manual (https://www.novell.com/documentation/privilegedusermanager22/npum_admin/data/bjfzqbd.html) it seems that you require `rush` to perform actions under authorized users. It seems pretty extense so I won't reproduce it but can you try Sections 5.2.2 and 5.2.5  and tell me what is it prompting?

Comment: Hi Cristian, thanks for checking back in. Well I'll surely try it and will let you know. The link you have shared in your answer there was some thing mentioned as subcommands of a main command I was doing some r&d on that but with no luck. Will read and try your this suggestion and will let you know.